# Why jQuery trigger function deletes data from array?

Tags: jquery

Please look at [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u964km3a/).

Here's the code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#click').click(function() {
    $(document).trigger('clicked', [1,2]);
  })
  
  $(document).on('clicked', function(event, data){
    console.log(data);
  });
})
```

If you see the code, what we get in console is `1` only.

It seems that jQuery strips the array and only shows the first element.

How should I fix this?

Comment: Your fiddle link is missing your code

Answer (score 1):

According to [`.trigger()`](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) you pass parameters with an array, but receive them with separate parameters.

Example from jquery.com:

```
$( "p" )
  .click(function( event, a, b ) {
    // When a normal click fires, a and b are undefined
    // for a trigger like below a refers to "foo" and b refers to "bar"
  })
  .trigger( "click", [ "foo", "bar" ] );
```

Applied to your code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#click').click(function() {
    $(document).trigger('clicked', [1, 2]);
  })

  $(document).on('clicked', function(event, data1, data2) {
    console.log(data1, data2);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='click'>
Click
</button>
```

---

As an extra, you can always use [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) which ignores the parameters and provides you with the arguments that were called.

Applying to your case, to get the original back as an array:

```
let data = [...arguments].slice(1);
```

The `slice(1)` is to remove the `event` parameter.

Updated snippet:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#click').click(function() {
    $(document).trigger('clicked', [1,2]);
  })
  
  $(document).on('clicked', function(event){
    let data = [...arguments].slice(1);
    console.log(data);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='click'>
Click
</button>
```